# How do I perform test action in Xcode with a scheduled bot?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, continuous-integration, xcode5

In Xcode 5 I have a bot setup to run on each new commit. It performs the analyze and archive actions. However I am unable to perform the test action because the option is disabled when creating or editing a bot, even though I have unit tests in my project.

How do I enable the test action so I can run unit tests on build?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Product->Scheme then choose the Scheme with which you run your bot, then choose Edit. Go to the section Test, and add your tests by clicking on the "+". Save Scheme, then edit your bot, and Test action will be enabled. If your bot does not want to run the test, restart Xcode service and try again. If it fail again, you need to create other bot.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to select / enable "Perform test action" in bot's settings. In safari choose Bot Settings -> Schedule -> Perform test action

Is that what you need?